# Postgresql Rollback investigation

Tags: postgresql, rollback

I have one PostgreSQL 40TB size of database and every day I face the high rollback rate after every hour. I just want to see the rollback details about session which call rollback, rolled back table name etc. How can I fetch this details from database. Thanks in advance.

[image: Here you can see rollback rate]

I didn't find any SQL or another way to fetch Rollback details

Comment: The term is "events tracing", see here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dynamic-trace.html - you could use DTrace to monitor the `transaction-abort` probe.

Comment: The 'spike' is up from essentially zero to still less than one per second. Is that really with pursuing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the log file. If the rollbacks were caused by errors, these errors should show up in the log. If there was no error, but the application deliberately ran `ROLLBACK`, the only way to log that is `log_statement = 'all'`, which can write so much log that it can impact database performance.

An alternative to `log_statement = 'all'` (if that is too much) is to set `log_transaction_sample_rate = 0.01`. Then one percent of your database transactions will be logged, which reduces the volume and still allows you to see enough `ROLLBACK` statements to figure out what is going on.

Comment: But the database is RDS and I can not get access to logfile

Comment: No access to the log file? Get a different service provider. You cannot run a database without access to the log. Where do you look if there is a problem?

Comment: RDS manage system administration team and they so far from me. Ok can you say me? If I will set log_statement = 'all' the rollback info will appear in the postgresql logfile yes?

Comment: It will. But beware: on a busy database, that can kill your application.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much